# How to merge two dataframes on list of columns and then deduplicate?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I have two dataframes that I would like to do a merge on `cols = ['male', 'age_cat', 'inpatient']`, and once merged then I would like to dedupulicate these on the left and right column `index` from each dataframe.

a:

```
       index  male  age_cat  inpatient
6885   34273   0.0      3.0        1.0
10145  50273   0.0      1.0        0.0
6099   30258   0.0      1.0        0.0
10834  53697   0.0      1.0        0.0
15267  76649   1.0      0.0        0.0
10122  50155   1.0      1.0        0.0
9210   45680   0.0      0.0        0.0
446     2221   1.0      3.0        0.0
38       196   1.0      0.0        0.0
14757  73363   1.0      0.0        0.0
450     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0
9617   47684   0.0      1.0        0.0
5285   26349   0.0      3.0        0.0
5666   28006   0.0      0.0        0.0
487     2475   1.0      2.0        0.0
671     3406   0.0      1.0        0.0
13398  66352   1.0      1.0        0.0
15525  78429   1.0      0.0        0.0
2831   14047   1.0      0.0        0.0
13361  66208   0.0      2.0        0.0
```

b:

```
         index  male  age_cat  inpatient
99629    99629     0        0          0
39305    39305     1        0          1
168799  168799     1        0          0
25276    25276     0        0          0
9964      9964     1        2          1
5137      5137     1        0          1
158488  158488     1        0          0
94960    94960     0        0          0
8955      8955     0        0          0
190425  190425     0        0          0
```

So, I do as follows:

```
mp=a.merge(b, on = cols)
```

and I get dataframe

mp:

```
    index_x  male  age_cat  inpatient  index_y
0     76649   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
1     76649   1.0      0.0        0.0   158488
2       196   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
3       196   1.0      0.0        0.0   158488
4     73363   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
5     73363   1.0      0.0        0.0   158488
6     78429   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
7     78429   1.0      0.0        0.0   158488
8     14047   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
9     14047   1.0      0.0        0.0   158488
10    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0    99629
11    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0    25276
12    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0    94960
13    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0     8955
14    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0   190425
15     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0    99629
16     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0    25276
17     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0    94960
18     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0     8955
19     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0   190425
20    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0    99629
21    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0    25276
22    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0    94960
23    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0     8955
24    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0   190425
```

which is  desired.

To  check expected number of pairings, I first check for specific conditions:

```
In [124]: a[(a.male==1)&(a.age_cat==0)&(a.inpatient==0)]
Out[124]:
       index  male  age_cat  inpatient
15267  76649   1.0      0.0        0.0
38       196   1.0      0.0        0.0
14757  73363   1.0      0.0        0.0
15525  78429   1.0      0.0        0.0
2831   14047   1.0      0.0        0.0
```

and

```
In [125]: b[(b.male==1)&(b.age_cat==0)&(b.inpatient==0)]
Out[125]:
         index  male  age_cat  inpatient
168799  168799     1        0          0
158488  158488     1        0          0
```

Thus, I expect **AT MOST** two matched pairs after deduplication, from whence my issue arises: To deduplicate the indices `index_x` and `index_y` in the dataframe `mp` I tried something along the lines of:

```
In [126]: mp[(~mp['index_x'].duplicated(keep='first'))&(~mp['index_y'].duplicated(keep='first'))]
Out[126]:
    index_x  male  age_cat  inpatient  index_y
0     76649   1.0      0.0        0.0   168799
10    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0    99629
```

But, as you see, I only get a single instance of `male==1, age_cat==0 and inpatient==0`instead of the expected two.

I've tried other methods with even less success.

I am merging on more than three elements and the dataframes are significantly much larger, but the issue is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can make a temporary column in both dataframes (e.g. `tmp`) and merge the dataframes by `cols` + this column:

```py
cols = ['male', 'age_cat', 'inpatient']

df_a['tmp'] = df_a.groupby(cols).cumcount()
df_b['tmp'] = df_b.groupby(cols).cumcount()

mp=df_a.merge(df_b, on = cols + ['tmp'])

print(mp)
```

Prints:

```
   index_x  male  age_cat  inpatient  tmp  index_y
0    76649   1.0      0.0        0.0    0   168799
1    45680   0.0      0.0        0.0    0    99629
2      196   1.0      0.0        0.0    1   158488
3     2237   0.0      0.0        0.0    1    25276
4    28006   0.0      0.0        0.0    2    94960
```